# variables mixing when loading one of them

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

im trying to write simple program in MASM and im noticed that my program is mixing varaibles while loading one of them.

Here's simple example example:

```
.386
.model FLAT, STDCALL
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
buffer2     db "34"
buffer1     db "60"

.data?
number1 dd  ?
number2 dd  ?

.code
start:

invoke  atodw, offset buffer1
mov    number1, eax;             ;Here eax=60 so it's ok


invoke  atodw, offset buffer2
mov    number2, eax              ;but here eax=3460

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

What more interesting i can change those valuses simple by switching variable order in .data section and then i will see (1)eax=6034 and (2)eax=34

So my question is: What Im doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "string" means in the MASM32 SDK always a **null-terminated** string. The assembler does not recognize a string in quotes as a string with null-termination, it's just a sequence of characters for it.

Whatever I removed was not needed - `masm32rt.inc` does it all:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
buffer2     db "34",0
buffer1     db "60",0

.data?
number1 dd  ?
number2 dd  ?

.code
start:

invoke  atodw, offset buffer1
mov    number1, eax;             ;Here eax=60 so it's ok

printf ("number1: %d\n",[number1])

invoke  atodw, offset buffer2
mov    number2, eax              ;but here eax=3460

printf ("number2: %d\n",[number2])

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

I'm sorry, I didn't understand the second question.